# update a field by removing quarter or removing month

Tags: sas

Second try out.

This is an excerpt of my table. I have 58 files in total.

```
var1               periode         adddate

ei_isbu_m.csv       m              56         
namq_nace10_k.csv   q              123
ei_cphi_m.csv       m              53
ei_isrt_m.csv       m              15
namq_aux_lp.csv     q              45
```

`var1` is the name of the files, `periode` is either `q` for quaterly and `m` for monthly and `adddate` is the number of days I'm adding to the current date.

What I want is the lastest publication date for each of the series and where the date is strictly inferior to my current date.

The publication date goes that way. For months, the publication date is the last month plus the adddate. For quaterly publication, it will be the end month of the quarter plus the add date.

Let's say we are using today's date is `12/01/2014`

`ei_isbu_m.csv` latest publication date will be `25/02/2014` as the last day of last month is 
`31/12/13`.

```
var1                    periode        adddate  date_publi_1 

ei_isbu_m.csv           m              56       25/02/14
namq_nace10_k.csv       q              123      03/05/14
ei_cphi_m.csv           m              53       22/02/14
ei_isrt_m.csv           m              15       15/01/14
namq_aux_lp.csv         q              45       14/02/14
```

However and as you can see, all the date of `date_publi_1` are superior to the 12/01/14.

So I need to figure out the lastest publication date that goes before `date_publi_1`. Therefore for quaterly publication, I'll need to remove an additional quarter which , will give me the end of September 2013 (30/09/13). And for the monthly publication, the reference month will be the end of November (30/09/13).

```
var1                    periode        adddate  date_publi_1  

ei_isbu_m.csv           m              56       25/01/14      
namq_nace10_k.csv       q              123      31/01/14      
ei_cphi_m.csv           m              53       22/01/14      
ei_isrt_m.csv           m              15       15/12/13      
namq_aux_lp.csv         q              45       14/11/13
```

As you can see again, there are still 3 files, for which the date is superior to my current date e.g. `ei_isbu_m.csv` , `namq_nace10_k.csv` and  `ei_cphi_m.csv`.

I need to remove one extra quarter for the quarter, which will give me the end of June (30/06/13). For the month, I'll need to remove one extra month, which will give me the end of October (31/10/13).

But, I'll keep the `date_publi_1` for `ei_isrt_m.csv` and `namq_aux_lp.csv`  as they are now inferior to my current date

Therefore for quaterly publication, I'll need to remove an additional quarter which , will give me the end of September 2013 (30/09/13). And for the monthly publication, the reference month will be the end of November (30/09/13).

```
var1                    periode        adddate  date_publi_1  

ei_isbu_m.csv           m              56       26/12/13   
namq_nace10_k.csv       q              123      31/10/13     
ei_cphi_m.csv           m              53       23/12/13
ei_isrt_m.csv           m              15       15/12/13      
namq_aux_lp.csv         q              45       14/11/13
```

My script is below. It is not working the way I want and I know for sure it is too lengthy. Worse I'm using a macro but I don't know how to do that other than with a macro.

Sorry for that but I've been struggling for some days already.

Any insights or help would be more than welcome.

Plus : I need to get more familiar with SAS coding but I feel that macro is not THE way or at least not the only way. Any tips (books, videos, else) for familiarizing myself with SAS coding will be welcome.

```
/*beginning of script*/
proc sql;
select var1 into :nomficq separated by ' ' from correspondance where periode
="q";
quit;

proc sql;
select ajoutdate into :ajoutdateq separated by ' ' from correspondance where periode
="q";
quit;

proc sql;
select var1 into :nomficmne777 separated by ' ' from correspondance where periode
="m" and ajoutdate ne 777;
quit;

proc sql;
select ajoutdate into :ajoutdatemne777 separated by ' ' from correspondance where periode
="m" and ajoutdate ne 777;
quit;

proc sql;
select var1 into :nomficm separated by ' ' from correspondance where periode
="m" and ajoutdate eq 777;
quit;

proc sql;
select ajoutdate into :ajoutdate separated by ' ' from correspondance where periode
="m" and ajoutdate ne 777;
quit;

%put nbfic: &nbfic ;
%put nomficq: &nomficq;
%put ajoutdateq: &ajoutdateq;
%put nomficmne777: &nomficmne777;
%put ajoutdatemne777: &ajoutdatemne777;
%put nomficm: &nomficm;
%put ajoutdate: &ajoutdate;

data correspondance;
set correspondance;
%do i=1 %to &nbfic;
if periode="q" and var1=&nomficq then do;
dern_date_trim_3=intnx('quarter',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-4,'E');
dern_date_publi_t_3=intnx('day',intnx('quarter',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-4,'E'),20);
dern_date_trim_2=intnx('quarter',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-3,'E');
dern_date_publi_t_2 =intnx('day',intnx('quarter',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-3,'E'),20);
dern_date_trim_1=intnx('quarter',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-2,'E');
dern_date_publi_t_1=intnx('day',intnx('quarter',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-2,'E'),20);
dern_date_trim_0=intnx('quarter',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1,'E');
dern_date_publi_t_0=intnx('day',intnx('quarter',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1,'E'),20);
format dern_date_publi_t_0 dern_date_trim_0 dern_date_publi_t_1 dern_date_trim_1 dern_date_publi_t_2 dern_date_trim_2 dern_date_publi_t_3 dern_date_trim_3 dern_dispo ddmmyy10.; 
end;
else if periode="m" and ajoutdate ne 777 and var1=&nomficm then do; 
   dern_date_mois_3=intnx('month',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-4,'E'); 
   dern_date_publi_m_3 =intnx('day',intnx('month',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-4,'E'),&ajoutdatemne777);
   dern_date_mois_2=intnx('month',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-3,'E'); 
   dern_date_publi_m_2 =intnx('day',intnx('month',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-3,'E'),&ajoutdatemne777);
   dern_date_mois_1=intnx('month',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-2,'E'); 
   dern_date_publi_m_1 =intnx('day',intnx('month',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-2,'E'),&ajoutdatemne777);
   dern_date_mois_0=intnx('month',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1,'E'); 
   dern_date_publi_m_0 =intnx('day',intnx('month',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1,'E'),&ajoutdatemne777);
   format dern_date_mois_3 dern_date_publi_m_3 dern_date_mois_2 dern_date_publi_m_2 dern_date_mois_1 dern_date_publi_m_1 dern_date_mois_0 dern_date_publi_m_0 dern_dispo ddmmyy10.; 
end;
else if periode="m" and ajoutdate eq 777 and var1=&nomficmne777 then do; 
   dern_date_mois_a_3=intnx('month',intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1),-4); 
   dern_date_publi_a_m_3 =intnx('day',intnx('month',intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1),-4),&ajoutdate);
   dern_date_mois_a_2=intnx('month',intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1),-3); 
   dern_date_publi_a_m_2 =intnx('day',intnx('month',intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1),-3),&ajoutdate);
   dern_date_mois_a_1=intnx('month',intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1),-2); 
   dern_date_publi_a_m_1 =intnx('day',intnx('month',intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1),-2),&ajoutdate);
   dern_date_mois_a_0=intnx('month',intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1),-1); 
   dern_date_publi_a_m_0 =intnx('day',intnx('month',intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1),-1),&ajoutdate);
   format dern_date_mois_a_3 dern_date_publi_a_m_3 dern_date_mois_a_2 dern_date_publi_a_m_2 dern_date_mois_a_1 dern_date_publi_a_m_1 dern_date_mois_a_0 dern_date_publi_a_m_0 dern_dispo ddmmyy10.; 
end;

if periode="q" and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_t_0 < date()  then ;
dern_dispo=dern_date_trim_0; 
else if periode="q" and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_t_1 <  date() 
then dern_dispo=dern_date_trim_1; 
else if periode="q" and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_t_2 <  date() 
then dern_dispo=dern_date_trim_2; 
else if periode="q" and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_t_3  <  date() then dern_dispo=dern_date_trim_3;

if periode="m" and ajoutdate ne 777 and var1=&nomficm and dern_date_publi_m_0  < date()  then ;
dern_dispo=dern_date_mois_0; 
else if periode="m" and ajoutdate ne 777 and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_m_1 <  date() 
then dern_dispo=dern_date_mois_1; 
else if periode="m" and ajoutdate ne 777 and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_m_2 <  date() 
then dern_dispo=dern_date_mois_2; 
else if periode="m" and ajoutdate ne 777 and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_m_3  <  date() then dern_dispo=dern_date_mois_3;

if periode="m" and ajoutdate eq 777 and var1=&nomficm and dern_date_publi_a_m_0 < date()  then ;
dern_dispo=dern_date_mois_a_0; 
else if periode="m" and ajoutdate eq 777 and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_a_m_1 <  date() 
then dern_dispo=dern_date_mois_a_1; 
else if periode="m" and ajoutdate eq 777 and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_a_m_2 <  date() 
then dern_dispo=dern_date_mois_a_2; 
else if periode="m" and ajoutdate eq 777 and var1=&nomficq and dern_date_publi_a_m_3  <  date() then dern_dispo=dern_date_mois_a_3;
%end;
run;

%mend;

%corresp;
/*end of script*/
```

Comment: This is much clearer.  Don't have time to write a real solution, but suggest something like: do i=1 by 1 until(newdate<today() );

Comment: This is much clearer.  Don't have time to write a real solution, but suggest psuedocode something like: do i=1 by 1 until(date_publ<today() ); date_publ=intnx(periode,date(),i,'E')+adddate; end; You would have to make periode be 'month' or 'quarter'.  So basically for each record, keep looping over intnx() calls backing up one period at a time until you find a date before today.  I can write real code later tonight if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: Hi Quentin, you hear me l'ami. I will try to do it myself but I would probably need some help. I'll put some stuff this afternoon. If you can amend me, it will be great :)

Comment: SOunds good.  I think my pseudocode in the do-loop should be more like: date_publ=intnx(periode,date_publ,-1);    But I'm no awake yet. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you want (or close):

```
data  have;
  input var1 $18. periode $7. adddate;
  cards;
ei_isbu_m.csv     month   56 
namq_nace10_k.csv quarter 123
ei_cphi_m.csv     month   53 
ei_isrt_m.csv     month   15 
namq_aux_lp.csv   quarter 45 
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  today="12Jan2014"d;
  do i=1 by 1 until (date_publ<today);
    date_publ=intnx(periode,today,-1*i,'E')+adddate;
  end;
  drop i;
  format date_publ today date9.;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Returns:

```
      var1           periode    adddate        today    date_publ

ei_isbu_m.csv        month         56      12JAN2014    26DEC2013
namq_nace10_k.csv    quarter      123      12JAN2014    31OCT2013
ei_cphi_m.csv        month         53      12JAN2014    23DEC2013
ei_isrt_m.csv        month         15      12JAN2014    15DEC2013
namq_aux_lp.csv      quarter       45      12JAN2014    14NOV2013
```

Comment: Hey Quentin,

Sounds good.

I've amended a bit

`data want;
  set have;
  today="12Apr2014"d;
  if adddate eq 777 then date_publ=intnx(periode,intnx('weekday',intnx(periode,today,0,'E'),-1),-1);
  else
  do i=1 by 1 until (date_publ<today);
  date_publ=intnx(periode,today,-1*i,'E')+adddate; 
  end;
  drop i;
  format date_publ today date9.;
run;
`